# Creating a Date Field based on conditions - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, history-tables

In python, I’ve set up a script that creates a table called ‘Today_DQ_Results’.  It runs a few SQL queries and concatenates the results to a single dataframe.  The script then pulls in the ‘Prior_Day_DQ_Results’ (i.e. results from yesterday), concatenates the results, and drops duplicate records so I have history table of all the DQ Issues.

My problem: I created a ‘date_identified’ field so we know when DQ issues have been identified, but I’m struggling to create a ‘DQ_Resolution_Date’ field for when DQ issues are resolved and no longer showing up in Today_DQ_Results (but such records would have shown up in Prior_Day_DQ_Results).

I will attached the code I've tried to create 'DQ_Resolution_Date'

```
# Define the queries
address_completeness = """SELECT ENTITY_ID, ADDRESS_LINE2 AS CONDITION_1, ADDRESS_LINE2 AS CONDITION_2, ENTITY_STATUS
FROM Table_1 
WHERE ADDRESS_LINE2 IS NULL"""

city_completeness = """SELECT ENTITY_ID, CITY_NAME AS CONDITION_1, CITY_NAME AS CONDITION_2, ENTITY_STATUS
FROM Table_1  
WHERE CITY_NAME IS NULL"""
    
Region_Subregion_Accuracy = """SELECT ENTITY_ID, DIVISION AS CONDITION_1, ENTITY_STATUS, SNDIVISION AS CONDITION_2
FROM Table_1
WHERE DIVISION <> SNDIVISION"""

# Execute the queries and save the results to dataframes
address_completeness_df = pd.read_sql(address_completeness, conn)
city_completeness_df = pd.read_sql(city_completeness, conn)
Region_Subregion_Accuracy_dr = pd.read_sql(Region_Subregion_Accuracy, conn)


# Add a new column called "DQ_Rule" to each dataframe and set its value accordingly
address_completeness_df['DQ_Rule'] = 'Address Completeness'
city_completeness_df['DQ_Rule'] = 'City Completeness'
Region_Subregion_Accuracy_dr['DQ_Rule'] = 'Region Subregion Accuracy'

# Combine the dataframes into a single dataframe
Today_DQ_Results = pd.concat([address_completeness_df, city_completeness_df, Region_Subregion_Accuracy_dr])

# Get current date in the format MMDDYY
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%y')

# Add a new column called "Unique_ID" with a unique identifier for each row
Today_DQ_Results['Unique_ID'] = [secrets.token_hex(3) + '_' + current_date for _ in range(len(Today_DQ_Results))]

# Create a new column called "Date_Identified" and set its value to today's date
Today_DQ_Results['Date_Identified'] = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Rearrange the order of columns
column_order = ['Unique_ID', 'ENTITY_ID', 'ENTITY_STATUS', 'DQ_Rule', 'CONDITION_1', 'CONDITION_2', 'Date_Identified']
Today_DQ_Results = Today_DQ_Results.reindex(columns=column_order)

#### Pull Yesterday's DQ File - Update Daily ####
file_path = r'C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\DQ Python\DQ_Summary_Report_6_12_23.xlsx'
Prior_Day_DQ_Results = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# combine the dataframes
Updated_DQ_Report = pd.concat([Prior_Day_DQ_Results, Today_DQ_Results], ignore_index=True)

# identify duplicate records
duplicates = Updated_DQ_Report.duplicated(subset=['ENTITY_ID', 'DQ_Rule', 'CONDITION_1', 'CONDITION_2'], keep=False)

# create a new 'DQ_Resolution_Date' column and set its value based on the presence of duplicates
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Updated_DQ_Report['DQ_Resolution_Date'] = np.where(duplicates, '', today)

# drop duplicates based on specified columns
Updated_DQ_Report = Updated_DQ_Report.drop_duplicates(subset=['ENTITY_ID', 'DQ_Rule', 'CONDITION_1', 'CONDITION_2'])

# Define a function to compare Date_Identified and DQ_Resolution_Date values
def update_resolution_date(row):
    if row['Date_Identified'] == row['DQ_Resolution_Date']:
        return ''
    else:
        return row['DQ_Resolution_Date']

# Apply the function to update DQ_Resolution_Date values
Updated_DQ_Report['DQ_Resolution_Date'] = Updated_DQ_Report.apply(update_resolution_date, axis=1)
Updated_DQ_Report.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Off topic, and maybe useless, but I think it’d greatly benefit for you to use an ORM: https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html if you’re writing SQL in code, you’re likely doing something wrong.

Comment: @Saturnix I appreciate the share. This project is new & a bit out of my wheelhouse, so that article is helpful.